# Deep copy of Poco::JSON::Object

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm trying to create deep copy of `Poco::JSON::Object`.

Internally `Poco::JSON::Object` uses pointers and copy constructor just copy those pointers. Is there a clever solution how to copy this structure using Poco framework?

Comment: The `makeStruct` function appears to do a deep copy, although that leaves you with a `Poco::Dynamic::Struct` and I dont see any potted function to convert that back to `Poco::JSON::Object` although you could write one bsed on the source of `makeStruct`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any generic solution, but for small JSON objects where performance is not critical the following function does the job well enough:

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr cloneJsonObject(Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr obj) {
    if (obj) {
        std::stringstream streamedObj;
        obj->stringify(streamedObj);
        Poco::JSON::Parser parser;
        return parser.parse(streamedObj).extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could not find good documentation. so here is another way of copying. you can check if the key and value need further deeper copy like using c_str(). for me this works fine.

```
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr cloneJsonObject(Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr obj)
{
    Poco::JSON::Object::Iterator it;
    Poco::JSON::Object *ptr = new Poco::JSON::Object;
    // loop and copy
    for(it = obj->begin(); it != obj->end(); it++)
        ptr->set(it->first, it->second);

    return ptr;
}
```